# R data.table find new encountered level within time period

Tags: r, data.table

### Background

I have a dataset of customers, their associated purchases and date of the purchase. I need to find a "next product". A next product is defined as a product that the customer hasn't bought in the previous 24 months and the next product will then be the current product. Notice that the name "next product" doesn't imply that I'm trying to predict anything. I just want to check if the customer has bought this particular product within the previous 24 months and if not, the next product is the current product.

### Data

Below is a minimal working example:

```
> test.dt
    ID   Product Diff_date
 1:  1 Product_C    0 days
 2:  1 Product_A   91 days
 3:  1 Product_A  122 days
 4:  1 Product_A  700 days
 5:  1 Product_A  700 days
 6:  1 Product_A  700 days
 7:  1 Product_A  731 days
 8:  1 Product_A  731 days
 9:  1 Product_C  761 days
10:  1 Product_A  761 days
11:  2 Product_A   30 days
12:  2 Product_B   60 days
13:  2 Product_C   91 days
```

And a data.table with the desired outcome, manually produced:

```
> test.dt.outcome
    ID   Product Diff_date Next_product
 1:  1 Product_C    0 days         None
 2:  1 Product_A   91 days         None
 3:  1 Product_A  122 days         None
 4:  1 Product_A  700 days         None
 5:  1 Product_A  700 days         None
 6:  1 Product_A  700 days         None
 7:  1 Product_A  731 days         None
 8:  1 Product_A  731 days         None
 9:  1 Product_C  761 days    Product_C
10:  1 Product_A  761 days         None
11:  2 Product_A   30 days         None
12:  2 Product_B   60 days         None
13:  2 Product_C   91 days         None
```

As we can see customer with ID = 1 has bought Product_C previously but not within the last 24*30 = 720 days, so the next product is then Product C. On the other we have customer with ID = 2 that has bought different products, but within the time period of 24 months, so we do not define a new product.

### Solution

I'm looking for a solution using the data.table package, but other approaches are also welcome.

### Dputs

```
library(data.table)
test.dt <- setDT(structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Product = c("Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", 
"Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", 
"Product_C", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_B", "Product_C"
), Diff_date = structure(c(0, 91, 122, 700, 700, 700, 731, 731, 
761, 761, 30, 60, 91), units = "days", class = "difftime")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Product", "Diff_date"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))


test.dt.out <- setDT(structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Product = c("Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", 
"Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_A", 
"Product_C", "Product_A", "Product_A", "Product_B", "Product_C"
), Diff_date = structure(c(0, 91, 122, 700, 700, 700, 731, 731, 
761, 761, 30, 60, 91), units = "days", class = "difftime"), Next_product = c("Product_C", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Product_C", 
"None", "None", "None", "None")), .Names = c("ID", "Product", 
"Diff_date", "Next_product"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))
```

Comment: didnt ID1 just bought ProductC in row 1? shouldnt you be suggesting that ID1 buy ProductB?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Yes he did, but the purchase in row 1 is over 24 months ago, so "it doesn't matter".

Comment: But you are saying ID1 just bought C again at 761 days, why would you suggest his next product should again be C? Also, a consecutive 24 month period != 720 days, problem seems more straight forward if you just provide dates and suggest something after 2 years.

Comment: @AndrewPruet You should'nt be to focused on the name "Next product". I'm not trying to predict anything. I just need to know if this customer has bought the product within the previous 24 months. If he hasn't the current product is going to be "Next product" whatever that means.

Comment: The data sets you provided don't contain `Product_C` at the first line (unlike what you previously showed). Also, the `test.dt.out` data set has `Product_C` in the first line in `Next_product` which doesn't resemble the desired output you described. Either-way, I think you could just do `test.dt[, Next_product := c(0, diff(Diff_date)) > 24*30, by = .(ID, Product)]`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Damnit. You are right. I edited the question and forgot to edit the datasets. But it looks like your provided solution is working - I will just test it and get back to you later.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It works as expected. I will correct the datasets and you can post your comment as an answer.